# mmap versus memory allocated with new

Tags: c++, performance, memory-management

I have a `BitVector` class that can either allocate memory dynamically using `new` or it can `mmap` a file. There isn't a noticeable difference in performance when using it with small files, but when using a 16GB file I have found that the mmap file is far slower than the memory allocated with `new`. (Something like 10x slower or more.) Note that my machine has 64GB of RAM.

The code in question is loading values from a large disk file and placing them into a Bloom filter which uses my `BitVector` class for storage.

At first I thought this might be because the backing for the mmap file was on the same disk as the file I was loading from, but this didn't seem to be the issue. I put the two files on two physically different disks, and there was no change in performance. (Although I believe they are on the same controller.)

Then, I used `mlock` to try to force everything into RAM, but the mmap implementation was still really slow.

So, for the time being I'm just allocating the memory directly. The only thing I'm changing in the code for this comparison is a flag the `BitVector` constructor.

Note that to measure performance I'm both looking at `top` and watching how many states I can add into the Bloom filter per second. The CPU usage doesn't even register on `top` when using `mmap` - although `jbd2/sda1-8` starts to move up (I'm running on an Ubuntu server), which looks to be a process that is dealing with journaling for the drive. The input and output files are stored on two HDDs.

Can anyone explain this huge difference in performance?

Thanks!

Comment: AFAIK, the default policy of mmap for reading large pages isnt pretty good. Can you rerun your case after setting MAP_POPULATE flag and using madvise as well with flags MADV_SEQUENTIAL (if your access is sequential) or MADV_RANDOM (if random access) OR'ed with MADV_WILLNEED (to prevent reloading of pages).

Comment: It's certainly an unexpected behavior, in particular because `operator new` uses `malloc` which uses `mmap` for large requests! When you say "using a 16GB file" that suggests you're using a _real_ file, not one from `/dev/shm`? If that's the case, and in particular since you notice the journalling process going up, the slowdown might be due to disk access for readahead and when faulting (though I wouldn't know what the OS should do on the disk for empty zero pages).

Comment: @Damon - I'm using a real file, not a temporary file. I am accessing it randomly, although if its locked into memory it doesn't seem like that should matter.

Comment: @ArunMu - good suggestions. The machine is busy now, but I will try those out in the morning.

Comment: Note that `/dev/shm` isn't really a temporary file, but it's a way of asking the OS "give me virtual memory", so if allocating memory is what you want (and _not_ read a real file) that is closer to what you want. Page faults should copy the zero page, and locking should not be necessary.

Comment: @ArunMu It looks like `MAP_POPULATE` is the key difference for this code. Enabling it gives the performance back. The `madvise(...)` call didn't seem to make much of a difference, and neither did `mlock(...)`. If you can provide an official answer to the question and provide a bit more info on why this is useful (the `man` page doesn't say too much), I'll accept your answer.

Comment: @NathanS. : Done. Let me know if something needs to be updated in the answer

Comment: @Arunmu Is there a reason to call `mmap` with `MAP_POPULATE` and then call `madvise` with `MADV_WILLNEED`? It seems that two calls do the same thing with respect to page prefaulting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to start with, `mmap` is an system call or interface provided to access the Virtual Memory of the system.

Now, in linux (I hope you are working on *nix) a lot of performance improvement is acheived by **lazy loading** or more commonly known as ***Copy-On-Write***.


For mmap as well, this kind of lazy loading is implemented. 


What happens is, when you call mmap on a file, kernel does not immediately allocate main memory pages for the file to be mapped.
 Instead, it waits for the program to write/read from the illusionary page, at which stage, a ***page fault occurs***, and the corresponding interrupt handler will then actually load that particular file part that can be held in that page frame (Also the page table is updated, so that next time, when you are reading/writing to same page, it is pointing to a valid frame).


Now, you can control this behavior with `mlock`, `madvise`, `MAP_POPULATE` flag with mmap etc.

`MAP_POPULATE` flags with mmap, tells the kernel to map the file to memory pages before the call returns rather than page faulting every time you access a new page.So, till the file is loaded, the function will be blocked.


From the Man Page:

```
MAP_POPULATE (since Linux 2.5.46)
              Populate (prefault) page tables for a mapping.  For a file
              mapping, this causes read-ahead on the file.  Later accesses
              to the mapping will not be blocked by page faults.
              MAP_POPULATE is supported for private mappings only since
              Linux 2.6.23.
```